# Using cNTLM & PuTTY to use HTTP/HTTPS through SSH Tunnel

Tags: tls, http, ssh

That's briefly the network topology I am facing:

```
My Workstation -> Transparent proxy (NTLM auth; only allows HTTPS port 443) -> Internet -> 
My PC at home (with SSH server listening on port 443, and with DDNS, so I have a domain)
```

I run cNTLM as a service, I think I configured it properly, in fact using PuTTY, I manage to connect successfully to my home SSH server, bypassing the proxy restriction in this way.

Those are briefly the cNTLM & PuTTY setups (I am in a Windows environment):

**Putty:**

```
Session
Host Name: my domain address (of my PC at home)
Connection type: SSH
Port: 443
Connection -> proxy
Proxy type: HTTP
Proxy hostname: localhost
Port: (the port cNTLM is listening at, for example 5555)
DNS lookup: Auto
Username/password: (my workstation user/pass)
```

**cNTLM:**

```
username: myworkstation username
domain: myworkstation domain
PassLM : myworkstation hashed pass
PassNT : myworkstation hashed pass
PassNTLMv2 : myworkstation hashed pass
Proxy: the proxy address with the port it is listening
Listen: the port cNTLM is listening, in this example 5555
```

As I said, I can successfully connect to my SSH server. What if I now want to use the just created SSH tunnel to browse the Internet?
I am sure that I must set the tunnel options, but should I use the tunnel option in the `CNTLM.ini` file, or the PuTTY SSH tunnel option? I performed many (unsuccessful) attempts, but clearly I'm missing something, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Legolas - one basic rule we have here is BE NICE!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to SSH tunnel a local port to remote 443 port, and then specify the local port in the browser proxy options. that was the part I was missing hope that can be useful to someone!